# C and bison: pointers to struct in %union definition

Tags: c, bison, unions

I'm having some trouble using pointers to structs in bison's union definition, as I need memory positions of these elements but all of them [seem to point to the same union position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29#C.2FC.2B.2B). Not sure If I'm using the right way. My code looks like:

main.h:

```
typedef struct _control *control;
struct _control { ... };

typedef struct _symbol *symbol;
struct _symbol { ... };
...
#include "parser.h"
```

parser.y

```
%{
    #include "main.h"
%}

%union {
    control ctrl;
    symbol s_head;
    symbol s_tail;
}
...
%%
...
%%
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    ...
    yylval.ctrl = malloc(sizeof(struct _control));
    yylval.s_head = malloc(sizeof(struct _symbol));
    yylval.s_tail = malloc(sizeof(struct _symbol));

    // This will give me the same memory position
    printf("%ld %ld %ld %ld\n",
        yylval, yylval.ctrl,
        yylval.s_head, yylval.s_tail);
    ...
}
```

Comment: In Bison (as in its predecessor Yacc), `%union` declares a C `union`, and you should probably read more about those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's the right way of doing it, but I just got my union elements mapped once I 'converted' them into a struct.

main.h

```
typedef struct _control *control;
struct _control { ... };

typedef struct _symbol *symbol;
struct _symbol { ... };

typedef struct _global *global;
struct _global { ... };
```

parser.y

```
%{
    #include "main.h"
%}

%union {
    global g;
}
...
%%
...
%%
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    ...
    yylval.g->ctrl->some_element ...
    yylval.g->s_head ...
    ...
}
```

Well, this just works.